# Linux: Setup PHP FastCGI for Monkey Server

Tags: php, linux, embedded, webserver, fastcgi

I'm trying to get PHP installed on my Linux device which already has Monkey Server installed, I do not have Apache installed. I want to be able to use FastCGI. I've downloaded and installed PHP7 according to [these](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/php.html) and [these](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-php-7-on-debian/) instructions and made sure the files are setup correctly; for the second link I did not install all of the packages listed at the beginning but most are already installed. The problem I am having is when I execute `/etc/init.d/php-fpm start` I get a list of errors which are generated from the script trying to run 
`/sbin/php-fpm`, the errors are as follows:

1. Starting php-fpm
2. /sbin/php-fpm: line 1: [Unit]: command not found
3. /sbin/php-fpm: line 2: PHP: command not found
4. /sbin/php-fpm: line 3: network.target: command not found
5. /sbin/php-fpm: line 5: [Service]: command not found
6. /sbin/php-fpm: line 8: --nodaemonize: command not found
7. /sbin/php-fpm: line 9: -USR2: command not found
8. /sbin/php-fpm: line 11: [Install]:
9. command not found ................................... failed

The `/sbin/php-fpm` file is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=@php_fpm_systemd@
PIDFile=@localstatedir@/run/php-fpm.pid
ExecStart=@sbindir@/php-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config @sysconfdir@/php-fpm.conf
ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR2 $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Lastly, I am running on a Yocto build of Linux so I do not have the luxury of `sudo apt-get install <package>`. The second hyperlink from above I couldn't complete the instructions involving the commands `insserv` and `systemctl` because those two commands are not present.
Any help is appreciated, I just want FastCGI on a lightweight server for embedded Linux. If there are better options I am open to them but Apache is too big.

## Edit:

I believe now my issues may be because I do not have `systemd` on my Linux distrubution which is why it is not handling items like `[Unit]`. Could someone please comment on this? I'm not familiar with `systemd`.

Answer (score 0):

Default Yocto build does not use systemd as init. For a lightweight server, I did recommend the lighttpd server and it has FastCGI support. Using Yocto you should build php and lighttpd and then transfer the php-cgi and  lighttpd-module-fastcgi ipk's generated to the module. php and lighttpd can be included in the image by having

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " php lighttpd"
```

in your local.conf file. The links that you refer to in your post are useless for Yocto.

Comment: I've already gotten PHP with Lighttpd working through FastCGI...it required more than the packages you've listed such as `php-cgi` and `lighttpd-module-fastcgi`. Not to mention a lot of configuration to get the two working together. This is why I wanted to use Monkey because it is easier to setup (at least in Ubuntu).

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that you would have to transfer the php-cgi and lighttpd-module-fastcgi ipk's to the module. I have used them and did not have to do a lot of configuration. But I am not expert.

Comment: Yes, I see that...missed it the first time. But I am interested in getting Monkey Server running and not Lighttpd (as the title states). I appreciate the effort but I am soon going to delete this question and revisit it when I have the time. Right now it's a `systemd` issue.